# why is my program skipping the if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

i tried to write my program in different ways but i couldnt figure it out .. the program execute only the code under else even even if the condition is verified 
can anyone help me please 
thanks

here is my code :

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
        String path=table.getValueAt(row, col).toString();
        String equipementMOID=txt.getText();

        if(table.isColumnSelected(4) ){
            if(table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString()=="UNIT" ){
                String equipementDate2=comboBox_10.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String xmlFile2=con.XMLSelection(equipementDate2);
                GetNode ne=new GetNode();
                try{
                    String equipementXml2=ne.nodeToString(xmlFile2, equipementMOID);
                    System.out.println(equipementXml2);
                    //GetNodeByPath node=new GetNodeByPath(equipementXml2,path);
                } 
                catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }    
            else{
                String equipementDate1=comboBox_9.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String xmlFile1=con.XMLSelection(equipementDate1);
                GetNode ne=new GetNode();
                try{
                    String equipementXml1=ne.nodeToString(xmlFile1, equipementMOID);
                    GetNodeByPath node=new GetNodeByPath(equipementXml1,path);
                } 
                catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }         
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: use equals() when comparing strings, instead of `==`

Comment: I didn't understand if you write the code what is the issue? If you not able to understand you code please modify the code as per your understand.

Comment: still not working by using equals() !

Answer (score 1):

Use the string.equals(String other) function to compare strings, not the == operator.

The function checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.
 If you actually want to test whether two strings have the same value you should use .equals()

```
 if(table.isColumnSelected(4) ){
                if(table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString().equals("UNIT") ){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead in `if` condition

```
table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString().equals("UNIT")
```

`==` actually checks the reference(consider it as the location where the `object` is getting stored) of the `String` object while `equals()` checks the `value` in case of `String`